# How to store List<Integer> in single-column table using Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have table consisting of single column *id*. Table is set of ids.

I want to load/save it to entity using Hibernate. I tried to use diffent annotations, so my code looks like this:

```
@Id
@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private List<Integer> playerIds;

public List<Integer> getPlayerIds() {
    return playerIds;
}

public void setPlayerIds(List<Integer> playerIds) {
    this.playerIds = playerIds;
}
```

So I want have one entity which contains all ids, and then I'll be able to check if there are some values in my DB.

Comment: That's not how it works. An entity represents one row of a table. But of course, you can use the entity manager to get an entity by its ID, or execute a query to find entities.